# Drawing many of one sprite will smudge the sprite

Tags: c#, sprite, monogame

I am making a tile-based game. I have my "playfield" that is 30*20 Tiles (each is 32x32 pixels). The first Tile that is drawn (at BlockPos (0,0)) is drawn correctly, but the other Tiles are drawn incorrectly. That is, the texture is "smudged". Here is the main class code:

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Texert.Content;
using Texert.Logic;

#endregion

namespace Texert
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class MainGame : Game
    {
        private FrameCounter _frameCounter = new FrameCounter();
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public MainGame()
            : base()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            Vars.Textures = new List<Texture2D>();
            Vars.Tiles = new List<Tile>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for (var k = 0; k < 30; k++)
                {
                    Vars.Tiles.Add(new TileDirt(new BlockPos(k, i)));
                }
            }

            // Set window size
            graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Tile.TILE_SIZE*20;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Tile.TILE_SIZE*30;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();


            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            Vars.Textures.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>("dirt"));

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here


            // Update FPS
            var deltaTime = (float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            _frameCounter.Update(deltaTime);
            Window.Title = "Texert - " + Math.Floor(_frameCounter.AverageFramesPerSecond) + " FPS";

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            foreach (var tile in Vars.Tiles)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(Vars.Textures[tile.textureIndex], 
                    tile.pos.GetRealPos().GetVector2(),
                        new Rectangle(tile.pos.GetRealPos().X, tile.pos.GetRealPos().Y,
                            Tile.TILE_SIZE, Tile.TILE_SIZE),
                                Color.White); // draw the fucking tile
            }

            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [screenshot of the game in action](http://imgur.com/8RFqWmj). I have no idea why it is drawn this way. How can I fix this?

Edit: Here's the Tile.cs file that contains Pos, BlockPos and Tile!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace Texert.Logic
{
    public class Tile
    {
        public static int TILE_SIZE = 32;
        public int textureIndex;
        public string tileName;
        public BlockPos pos;

        public Tile()
        {
            textureIndex = 0;
            tileName = "null";
            pos = new BlockPos(0, 0);
        }

        public Tile(int index, string name, BlockPos pos)
        {
            textureIndex = index;
            tileName = name;
            this.pos = pos;
        }
    }

    public class BlockPos
    {
        public Pos actualPos;
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public BlockPos(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public Pos GetRealPos()
        {
            return new Pos(X*Tile.TILE_SIZE, Y*Tile.TILE_SIZE);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns blockpos of pos, rounded down to nearest multiple of TILE_SIZE
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pos">The position to convert to BlockPos</param>
        /// <returns>The BlockPos</returns>
        static BlockPos GetBlockPosFromPos(Pos pos)
        {
            return new BlockPos(pos.X % Tile.TILE_SIZE, pos.Y % Tile.TILE_SIZE);
        }
    }
    public class Pos
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public Pos(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public Vector2 GetVector2()
        {
            return new Vector2(X, Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to create a tile-based game myself, but I am using SFML graphics lib and C#. Sorry, I have not worked on XNA Framework, so I cant help you with this question. But I hope we can exchange experience and ideas :)

Comment: It looks like the bug might be in the BlockPos class. Post that code so we can have a look.

Comment: @DylanWilson the BlockPos class is in the Tile.cs file. I have added the contents of the file to the OP! (It's just a wrapper for my (crappy) coords system)